# How did this project rug? Minting new tokens, I tried to find it but i'm unable to see how they did it

Tags: solidity

this is their contract:

https://bscscan.com/address/0x95d25105237ced24523bbc3880b2551248e90de2#code

I cannot find the minting function in the contract, also how would they be able to call it?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the contract is full of red flags

- `subs`, `sub` in SafeMath
- `_decimals`, `decimal`
- `uint256 Address` confusing name for a variable
- `uint256 _taxFee = 5` and `uint256 _liquidityFee = 5` are never used
- `approved` functions altering balances

The minting was done with the `_burn` function:

```
function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) public virtual {
    require(account == governance, "ERC20: Burner is not allowed");
    _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount);
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
}
```

It uses `.sub()` from SafeMath which add numers instead

```
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns(uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
    return c;
}
```